# nmap scanning a slow host

Tags: nmap

Is there way how to enforce nmap waiting for replies longer (10 seconds)? I want to scan an embedded device which utilizes some sleep modes and it process packets from wi-fi module with very high delay of several seconds (pings shows delay in range 3 - 8 seconds. If I run nmap using following parameters (which are inspired by zenmap default profile `Intense scan with UDP`):

```
nmap -sS -sU -T4 -A -v -oX aaaaaa.xml 192.168.XXX.YYY
```

it fails at first ping marking the host 192.168.XXX.YYY down. I tried adding recommended `-Pn` flag but it fails for similar reason one step further - at ARP ping.

```
Host discovery disabled (-Pn). All addresses will be marked 'up' and scan times will be slower.
Starting Nmap 7.91 ( https://nmap.org ) at 2023-09-27 23:23 CEST
NSE: Loaded 153 scripts for scanning.
NSE: Script Pre-scanning.
Initiating NSE at 23:23
Completed NSE at 23:23, 0.00s elapsed
Initiating NSE at 23:23
Completed NSE at 23:23, 0.00s elapsed
Initiating NSE at 23:23
Completed NSE at 23:23, 0.00s elapsed
Initiating ARP Ping Scan at 23:23
Scanning 192.168.XXX.YYY [1 port]
Completed ARP Ping Scan at 23:23, 1.44s elapsed (1 total hosts)
Nmap scan report for 192.168.XXX.YYY [host down]
NSE: Script Post-scanning.
Initiating NSE at 23:23
Completed NSE at 23:23, 0.00s elapsed
Initiating NSE at 23:23
Completed NSE at 23:23, 0.00s elapsed
Initiating NSE at 23:23
Completed NSE at 23:23, 0.00s elapsed
Read data files from: /usr/bin/../share/nmap
Nmap done: 1 IP address (0 hosts up) scanned in 3.65 seconds
           Raw packets sent: 2 (56B) | Rcvd: 0 (0B)
```

Is there way to set timeout when waiting for all replies?